# How to track a Neo4j query which is still running (after a long time!)?

Tags: neo4j

Using the neo4j browser, I sent a query which is still running after 6 hours :( I wanna know is it really working and doing something or it's already done and the browser for some reason (like lost connection) wasn't updated.

(**** Update after reading comments ****)
Here is my query:

```
explain LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/.../userToken.csv" AS csvrow
MATCH (u:User)
where u.userID = toInt(csvrow.userID)
MATCH (u)-[:MADE]->(twt: Tweet)-[r: CONTAINS]->(tok: Token)
SET r.user_score = toFloat(csvrow.score)
```

I need to update the :CONTAINS relation between :Tweet and :Token nodes and add a new properties (user_score) from csv file. There is and index on :Token(word), :User(userID) and :Tweet(tweetID). As @ Tim suggested I used EXPLAIN and got this warnning:

```
The execution plan for this query contains the Eager operator, which forces all
 dependent data to be materialized in main memory before proceeding.

Using LOAD CSV with a large data set in a query where the execution plan contains 
the Eager operator could potentially consume a lot of memory and is likely to not 
perform well. See the Neo4j Manual entry on the Eager operator for more 
information and hints on how problems could be avoided.
```

So do you have any suggestion to improve it?

Comment: Six hours??? How large is your database? And what query did you run? And did you query on indexed properties? (probably a good thing to edit your question to show this info).

Comment: I asked the same question - there doesn't appear to be any monitoring tools you can use to see what's going on in the db.

Comment: re-enter the query with the word "explain" at the front and it'll give you a diagram of what it'll do - that'll give you an indication of how much work its doing.